# how to configure a spring+hibernate+mysql project?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, c3p0

i use spring3 hibernate4 and struts2 building a web project,and I used c3p0,my project can running on my server,but after about 10 hours,the tomcat was stopped automatically,i know that's beacause of my configuration files,and because of the db connection,i readed many article,but still does not work well.
there is my configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.jdbcUrl}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="7200" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="200" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="270" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery">
        <value>SELECT 1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and I saw some warning in my log file like this

```
05-Apr-2016 18:30:32.497 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
```

and when I close the tomcat there are some errors to
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFlPj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this property :

```
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckout " value="true" />
```

And Check this `c3p0` steps on how to [test connection](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing) for further details